# macOS Ventura - How do I set a timer in Clock.app from command line?

Tags: ventura, clock

I want to set timers (see screenshot below) in Clock.app from command line on macOS Ventura,
How do I do that?
[image]

Comment: Is there a reason it must be called from the command line?  Will AppleScript work?

Comment: AppleScript will not work with the Clock app. Why do you need a timer? You could just use sleep for a set time then loop "tput bel" to ring your alarm.

Comment: @Allan @ErniePC12 Thanks for the comments. Yeah I think `sleep && say "Time is up"' also work for my use cases. It doesn't have to use AppleScript, I listed as a tag because I thought it was a possible solution.